# How to disable HTTP/2 for appengine hosted GO server?

Tags: google-app-engine

Google Appengine automatically enabled HTTP/2 protocol for any server hosted on Appengine. How can I disable this?

Comment: Could you share some more details as for why you would want to disable it? According to [this documentation](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/10/Full-Speed-Ahead-with-HTTP2-on-Google-Cloud-Platform.html), http/2 reuqests are translated into http/1.1 automatically for App Engine. In that document there is more info in case you want to negotiate http/2, for what you could use a Compute Engine instance.

Comment: Thanks, Pablo! I am suspecting that http/2 is causing this https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/81310